# Is there a query to get all the unaswered questions for my favorite tags?

Tags: feature-request, tags

Is there a single bookmarkable query URL that list all unanswered qestions that contain at least one of my favorite tags? Preferably, this should be dynamic, so that if I add or remove favorite tags I do not have to modify that url. Something like `http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/taggedwithmyfavorites`

Answer (score 2):

```
http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/tag1 or tag2 or tag3 or tag4
```

works, but you have to modify it when you modify your favorites.